# User import from Salesforce Identity to Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-active-directory

We have clients using Salesforce Identity and we want to move them to Azure Active Directory B2C. I want to ask if it is possible to migrate the users from SalesForce Identity to Azure AD B2C along with the passwords so that the users do not have to change/reset their passwords?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Azure AD graph API for it.

The user migration process falls into two flows:

Pre-migration: This flow applies when you either have clear access to a user's credentials (user name and password) or the credentials are encrypted, but you can decrypt them. The pre-migration process involves reading the users from the old identity provider and creating new accounts in the Azure AD B2C directory.

Pre-migration and password reset: This flow applies when a user's password is not accessible. For example:
The password is stored in HASH format.
The password is stored in an identity provider that you can't access. Your old identity provider validates the user credential by calling a web service.

Please refer to this document for detailed steps - [Azure Active Directory B2C: User migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration)